# divided textbox besides the the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to add a box like the one in the attached image besides the graph. 
i tried the following code , but it shows one box ( and i expect that),but how can i create textbox devided by customizd the lines (e.g. like the attached image. please see the code i use. Thank you for the support

```
    plt.gcf().text(0.6, 0.82,cardtext, fontsize=14, bbox=dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='black'))
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at matplotlib's [table](https://matplotlib.org/api/table_api.html#matplotlib.table.Table)

Comment: Thanks but i cant make it with the table next to the graph